# MEF and MVC - a few pointers please :)

Tags: mef, asp.net-mvc-3

What I am trying to do is inject a component into my MVC app and make use of it from the controllers.

Currently I am not trying to use MEF for the actual controllers, but i want to import components e.g. A loggin component into the MVC app.

Where is the best place to do this?

Currently I have, directly in the controller, put my compose parts code and ILogger property, but I get the feeling this is not the best way.  Seems like I should only need to call Compose once in the application.
So should it be in the global asax file that I do the compose?
If so, how do I get a handle on ILogger from my controllers? Should I have a "base" controller, where i inject ILogger into the constructor and inherit every standard controller from?

Hope that makes sense - I'm just struggling a bit with the structure of my code.

Thx

Comment: http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=259 This blog post might help you. It's all about MVC3 and MEF.

Comment: also don't forget about this http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=88

Answer (score 0):

I use Log4Net and inject the logger into each controller.  I dont think its a big hit when you use injection.  Take a look at Ninject.  It has both an MVC implementation and a logging module.  The modules are loaded once in the global, then it injects the controllers.  Basic DI, but do you really need more?  If you create a base controller you will still have to create a ctor in each controller that can be injected.

You might create a base controller with the logging, then use property injection.  I have never done this, but if all controllers use the same base it should work fine.

Comment: For the logger I use a static encapsulation of log4net. Makes it really easy to log everything. And you don't risk having more loggers trying to access the same resources.

Comment: I'm using NLog...not that it really makes a great deal of difference.
I'm starting to think that Ninject or windsor may be a better solution than MEF for what I want to do!  @Paw...do you create your static encapsulation in the global.asax?